# Graphical glitching when offsetting GameObject from the Mouse location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attemping to drag a gameobject with the mouse, while retaining the distance between the object and mouse while dragging. The problem I have is, when facting in the distance into my code, a graphical glitch occurs. I have no idea why.

I have tried changing the order in which the coordinates are calculated, as well as using Unity Camera methods such as WorldToScreenPoint() for the GameObject.

The code works fine without the offset being factored in, but I want to retain the offset, so it is accurate as possible.

```cs
public void DragObject(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        if (!bDebugEnabled) return;

        offset =  Input.mousePosition - eventData.selectedObject.transform.position;
        eventData.selectedObject.transform.position = Input.mousePosition + offset;
    }
```

I expect the GameObject to move while maintaining the offset distance from the mouse. For example, dragging the GameObject at its corner would be maintained while dragging.

The actual result is that the GameObject snaps between two positions in close proximity to the mouse. Result can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d79c.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `DragObject(BaseEventData eventData)`method is called every frame.
So, the `offset` is recalculated every frame, and since you moved the `gameObject`, it’s different.
You should calculate `offset` only when the player initially clicks on the object.

```
offset =  Input.mousePosition - eventData.selectedObject.transform.position;
```

This line should be on a method that is only called on the initial click on the object, and the rest should be updated for the whole duration of the drag.